# How to run Kivy and the XLRD module properly

Tags: python, excel, kivy, xlrd

I am attempting to make a very simple app in Kivy using the xlrd module. I have an excel spreadsheet with some data and I want to show the cell (2,1) as a label. Here is my code so far:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
import xlrd
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Actuarial program for BAM.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='sheet.cell_value(2,1)')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

First of all I understand that the label will only give me the literal text  sheet.cell_value(2,1). My problem lies with the workbook and sheet variables. If I try to run the program nothing happens. However, if I comment the two lines out ('workbook =', and 'sheet ='), then the program will run, opening up a window from Kivy with the text sheet.cell_value(2,1). Is there a problem with the way I have formatted the code?

Additionally, the excel file is in the same directory as the .py program.

Answer (score 0):

`Label(text='sheet.cell_value(2,1)')` displays `sheet.cell_value(2,1)` literally since it's quoted.
You have to unquote it, and since `sheet` is a class member, you have to prefix it by `self` or `MyApp`. I'd go with the `self` prefix for instance:

```
class MyApp(App):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Actuarial program for BAM.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    def build(self):
        return  Label(text=self.sheet.cell_value(2,1))
```

if the `xlsx` file is in the same directory as the program I'd recommend this (and would catch exceptions & display them):

```
    # find out where is the script/executable installed
    program_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable if getattr( sys, 'frozen', False ) else __file__)
    try:
        # open the file from the same directory so script works from any cwd
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(program_dir,'Actuarial program for BAM.xlsx'))
    except Exception as e:
          print("Exception occurred: {}".format(str(e)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the program still won't execute/give me a kivy window. Just to clarify, the `program_dir` and `workbook` lines you wrote are meant to be under `class MyApp(App):` correct?

Comment: yes. In your question you're saying that you comment out something, and it works, but I'm not sure of what you're commenting.

Comment: `#workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Actuarial program for BAM.xlsx')`
`#sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)` when these two lines of code are commented out, Kivy will run and open a window.

Comment: see my edit. I added protection against exceptions. Try that, maybe you'll see an error where you didn't before.